# Python Threading wait for return

Tags: python

I have a list auf URLs which have to be fetched in parallel, therefore I use threading:

```
for url in urls:
    thread = fetch_single(url)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
    # thread.html() is always "None" here:
    thread.html()
```

My threading worker class:

```
class fetch_single(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.response = None

    def run(self):
        self.response = consumer.fetch(self.url)

    def html(self):
        return self.response.getData()
```

My problem is the line `self.response = consumer.fetch(self.url)`. How can I achieve, that the thread waits for the response from the subroutine/class?

Answer (score 0):

This is a alternative solution.
You would need to check if each individual thread is "alive" or has completed its task. A quick piece of code to show you the logic would be this:

```
import threading
import time

requests = {}
urls = ['www.google.se', 'inbox.google.com']

class fetch_single(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.response = None

    def html(self):
        return self.response.getData()

    def run(self):
        self.response = consumer.fetch(self.url)
        requests[self.url] = self.html()

for url in urls:
    thread = fetch_single(url)
    thread.start()

while len(threading.enumerate()) > 1:
    time.sleep(1)

for url in requests:
    html = requests[url]
```

the `while len(threading.enumerate()) > 1` would check if all child-threads have been completed/killed but the main thread (your script) is still alive.
Normally in this loop you'd check against a value inside the thread or have some sort of communication system with the threads to check if it's done processing.

But this will give you a better platform to start off from.

Also note that I chose to save your HTML data in a global variable called `requests` instead of fetching it from the thread because that will be a locking operation. normally you'd do something such as:

```
def check_html(self):
    if self.respones:
        return true
```

Note that you'd replace `while len...` with:

```
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    thread.check_html()
```

or something along those lines best suited to your needs.

Comment: Is there a more responsive approach without sleep or busy waiting? Something like an interrupt (back to the main process to check if all threads are completed) after a thread has terminated? I want to use it as a web service and therefore response time is crucial...

Comment: @RoyalKnight You could use `threads.join()` and that should wait for all processes to terminate. You'd simply have to replace the `while .. sleep` method with that, at least it should work with my model.. But i'd have to double check.

Comment: But that's what I implemented already? My understanding is, that `thread.join()` should wait until the thread is terminated, therefore the result should not be `None`?

Comment: @RoyalKnight the problem is that you're running `thread.html()` on a terminated thread. So the logic you're using won't work. Or i might be totally wrong here but in my experience you should return values and work with functions on live threads not dead ones.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the scope of `consumer`. I had to inject `consumer` into the `fetch_single` class:

```
class fetch_single(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self, consumer, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.consumer = consumer
        self.url = url
        self.response = None

    def run(self):
        self.response = self.consumer.fetch(self.url)

    def html(self):
        return self.response.getData()
```